# Whenever I type, my media player slows right down.. and I don't know why?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, media-player

It is the same with SMPlayer or VLC media player.. It's a WIN XP machine.  I've noticed this with any other machine.  Also, it seems to take a while to type out..

Comment: Does the machine affected have a single core processor while the others have dual core?

Comment: Yes, it possibly does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a USB Keyboard, and it stopped.. so I don't know WHY but I thought I would pass on the solution

Answer (score 0):

What application are you typing in at the time? I know dreamweaver has/had an issue where updating design  and code view caused the cpu to go nuts.

Comment: Just IMs like MSN and so on, Pidgin I believe, or Digsby

Comment: I'd shut down all other apps. Then open your IM clinet and the task manager to the cpu graph, and just start typing and see if the cpu spikes. That way you can get a baseline of the cpu usage.



I'm running a mobile pentium and have never experienced something like that before.

Comment: I agree. I have seen times when simply typing anywhere (even the Run dialog) would go so slow that each characters appears one-at-a-time, each one taking a second or two. Whenever that has happened, it was always because something was sucking up CPU cycles, usually in >Normal priority.